# Issue in SELECT query in WP - count the number of times a string appears in DB

Tags: mysql, select

I have `meta_key` in `postmeta` table as `first_group_class` that it's value is serialized and I can not use `WP_Query`. Because I want to know the count of special string (e.g: '#23#') that is repeated in all the meta values in the `postmeta` table.

**Note:** consider that we can even have several from that special string in one meta value.
I've used the following but it can not count that:
**in fact** i want to count the number of times that string appears in a DB.

```
<?php
$mysql_query = "
    SELECT *
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
    WHERE meta_key = 'first_group_class'
    AND meta_value LIKE '#23#'
";

$countstar = $wpdb->get_results( $mysql_query );

echo 'count: ' . count( $countstar ) . '<br>';
```

How should I solve that?

Comment: A sample data set and desired result might be useful

Comment: @Strawberry my friend, did you ger what i mean?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @Strawberry i changed the `title` and add a part to the question

Answer (score 0):

i could not find the solution by SELECT query but i solved it in another way:

```
$post_ids = get_posts( array('fields' => 'ids', 'post_type' => 'class') );
foreach($post_ids as $post_id) {
      $postmeta = serialize(get_post_meta( $post_id, $key = 'first_group_class', true ));
      $count= substr_count($postmeta ,"#23#");
      $sum+= $count;
}
echo '<br>count= '.$sum.'<br>';
```